# Excel Match() returns #N/A error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've a problem with the MATCH formula in Excel. See the attached file for the problem.

```
Bron bestand:           
MAY 16  MAY 16  APR 16  APR 16
PANELMARKET PANELMARKET PANELMARKET PANELMARKET
SALES TH,PIECES SALES PIECES %  SALES TH,PIECES SALES PIECES %
14.1    100     12.3    100
1.7     100     1.7     100
5.5     100     5.5     100
0.1     100     0.1     100
```

File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8cojNLiVOAyWXh2WlpwOGczcDA/view?usp=sharing

The strange thing is it gives the error on Excel for Windows (English version), but not on my Dutch Mac OSX version... It seems that it has something to do with date values, but I can't fix it.

Comment: What attached file?

Comment: Sorry was too fast :-). File is added.

Answer (score 1):

The space character is a non-breaking space (ASCII 0160) not a space character (0032). While it is not common in typed data, it is typical in data copied from a web page.

Use `=CODE(MID(A$5, ROW(1:1), 1))` and fill down (and right) to retrieve the ASCII codes for each character.

As further proof, this works just fine but I would suggest fixing the data so you do not run into similar problems in the future..

```
=MATCH("MAY"&CHAR(160)&"16", $A$5:$D$5, 0)
```

Comment: also pretty well showed [HERE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Remove-spaces-and-nonprinting-characters-from-text-023f3a08-3d56-49e4-bf0c-fe5303222c9d) ;)